# How to get absolute path of image and includes files with 2 different domains And different document root folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have two domains.

1. Www.abc.com
2. Www.xyz.com

Now, I have one domain hosted at my cloud server, which is www.abc.com

And I have a folder in www.abc.com = **www.abc.com/appFolder/app1/**

Now I have hosted my another domain at the same cloud server using virtual host configuration in apache with document root folder for this domain to point out: at the above folder.

So basically when somebody is going to **www.xyz.com** then they are viewing the page at **www.abc.com/appFolder/app1/**

My problem is, I have database connection config file situated at the root folder, i.e. At www.abc.com So this is why when I go to my abc.com everything works fine. But now in case of xyz.com it is unable to find the config file??

How i can use config file there?? Also in case of accessing the image.

If I am in abc.com then I can access file by doing ../../image.jpg but in case of xyz.com it is not able to find the image file by doing this. I understand it is because of different document root folders. But is there any way that I can deal with this issue??

Answer (score 0):

It should not change anything for your database connection. Config files are accessed with local paths. They are not related to domains.

For images, you could use absolute url and load images on www.abc.com even if users are on www.xyz.com. Or, you can detect url in request prameter and adjust paths. A simple  in the header can define base url for all links in your page.